# How to easily change tables from Excel to Markdown

Tags: excel, markdown

So I am trying to learn Neural Network by Visualizing it via putting it in excel.

The table looks something like this:
[image: Neural Net]

I have to make this table in a markdown table so that I can put it up on GitHub. Is there some easy way to convert tables from Excel to Markdown as there are a whole lot number of tables just like this and it would take a huge amount of time to make it into markdown manually.

Comment: Yes this is an old question, but exactly what I was searching for. The answers here didn't worked for me (dunno why). But this python implementation worked like charm: https://github.com/mplewis/csvtomd

Comment: Have you tried converting excel to csv? Github supports csv rendering. It won't be part of md but at least you could create a link on your .md that when clicked it presents you the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandoc seemed a little complicated to me and would have to understand another software just to get this simple task done. I used [Typora](https://typora.io/) to do this task. I was able to just copy the tables directly from MS Excel into the WYSIWYG editor of Typora and it will automatically generate Markdown code for the same.

Sorry if this answer is not upto the Stack Overflows's standards, but hey if someone else is looking for the same, it will help.

Comment: For me it is even better to use the site: https://tableconvert.com/excel-to-markdown

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I would export to csv from Excel, then using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) and the [pandoc-placetable](https://github.com/mb21/pandoc-placetable) filter:

```
pandoc-placetable --file=foo.csv | pandoc -f json -t gfm
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this today. May I know where to post such questions, for next time. Isn't it a valid question, related to Markdown?

Comment: @sin2akshay Well, Markdown-questions are fine on Stackoverflow, while general Excel questions should go to https://superuser.com. But see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask But I agree, it's sometimes confusing and not clear-cut.

Comment: "I guess this question is off-topic for Stackoverflow." Then by all means, don't answer but use your close-vote privileges.